# Remove \n (new line) between two characters

Tags: csv, sed, awk

I try with awk or sed to remove \n when they are two tag.

Exemple :
a csv file frame with new line in a one column. I need to remove this new line but not the text and not the new line between each row.

```
row1-col1;row1-
col2;
row2-col1;row2-
col2;
```

Should look like:

```
row1-col1;row1-col2;
row2-col1;row2-col2;
```

I have try many filter without succes and now i'm a bit confuse.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 1):

If it's really just a matter of concatenating every other line, you can do something like this:

```
awk '(NR % 2) == 1 { saved=$0; next; } { printf("%s%s\n", saved, $0); }' file.txt
```

The first clause saves every odd-numbered line without printing, and the second prints that saved line followed by the current line, without an intervening newline.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '{if ($0~/;$/)print $0;else printf $0}' file
```

Comment: Never use `print $0`, use `printf "%s",$0` instead. Try it when the input file contains "%s" or some other printf formatting directive.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are always split at `-` then you can use the following `sed` script:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/-\n/-/g' file.txt
```

Comment: @Barney I am so sorry but I can't verify it on Mac terminal. I am on Ubuntu and it works as expected on my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`. It appends all input until last line (`$!`) and then removes all newlines with a preceding `-`.

```
sed -n ':a ; $! { N; b a }; s/-\n/-/g ; p' infile
```

It yields:

```
row1-col1;row1-col2;
row2-col1;row2-col2;
```

Comment: I tried this, but there was no output at all. I'm using a mac terminal if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file                      
row1-col1;row1-
col2;
row2-col1;row2-
col2;

$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?"":"\n")}1' file
row1-col1;row1-col2;
row2-col1;row2-col2;
```